# My WPF tabControl_SelectionChanged event only fires when the form is opening

Tags: c#, wpf

I could have sworn i had this working but... In my XAML I have

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" FontWeight="Bold" SelectionChanged="tabControl_SelectionChanged">
```

and in my code behind i have

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (tabBDEAdjust.IsSelected)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("hello");
     e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Now the SelectionChanged event only fires once when the program opens. How can i get it working again?

Comment: Does it really only fire once as opposed to the if condition only being true once?

Comment: @HB. No. Just once on opening.

Comment: If you negate that question it does fire and your if condition just needs to be changed.

Comment: @HB  Even if I negate it. The tabControl_SelectionChanged event never fires again.

Comment: Something else is happening that you're not showing us then.  You changing `tabControl` in codebehind or something. (PS, you wouldn't have this problem following MVVM :) )

Comment: @JimDel: Then it is as Kevin said: Something else is happening, because that code does not display anything that would lead to such a behaviour.

Comment: I agree. I put the same code in a new project and it works fine. Thanks. I'll look into it with that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the posters of the comments. They helped lead me in the right direction. I found my partners code below to be the cause.

```
tabControl.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(tabControl_SelectionChanged);
```